# GItlab: has there any way we can select the variable values as drop down menu

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In Gitlab ci We have declared our variables like below

```
 USER_NAME:
    value: ""  
    description: "Enter Username"
  File_Name:
    description: "Enter the file name"
```

It only give a text box where We can enter the value.

Can I make a drop down select box is there any option available to make it a select box.Then we can select the value from drop down.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[GitLab 15.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/12/22/gitlab-15-7-released/#select-predefined-cicd-variables-values-from-a-dropdown-list) (December 2022) has finally implemented this:

> ### Select predefined CI/CD variables values from a dropdown list
>
> Previously, you could [pre-fill CI/CD variables in the “Run pipeline” page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/index.html#prefill-variables-in-manual-pipelines), with a specific value.
>
> Unfortunately, if you had multiple options for the variable’s value, you still had to manually input the option you wanted. This was an error-prone process because you could easily input an invalid value, or just mistype it.
>
> In this release, we’ve added the ability to set a list of values which are surfaced in a drop-down list in the “Run pipeline” page.
>
> Now you can define the exact list of values that are valid for each CI/CD variable when running a pipeline manually, greatly simplifying your workflow when using manually-triggered pipelines.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_7/prefill.png -- Select predefined CI/CD variables values from a dropdown list]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/index.html#prefill-variables-in-manual-pipelines) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29159).

Comment: Thanks to gitlab team...Thank you VonC

Answer (score 3):

No it is not possible. What we ended up doing, if we want to have a better configurable way, was using the gitlab pages with a form, which will use the API or a `POST` to create a new pipeline. This way we are quiet flexible with the options to provide to the users.

Comment: can you please provide the api that set the variable values and run it

Answer (score 2):

I see an active proposal for it https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29159 (almost 2 years). But no activity for the moment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible yet
Backend ticket is created for it May 19, 2022

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/362934

Original proposal https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29159

Comment: I guess this is one of the most awaited features from `Gitlab` and also a reason for sticking to good old `Jenkins`

Answer (score 0):

It's already implemented in GitLab v15.7 (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/index.html#prefill-variables-in-manual-pipelines):

For example:

```
variables:
  DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT:
    value: "staging"
    options:
      - "production"
      - "staging"
      - "canary"
    description: "The deployment target. Set to 'staging' by default."
```