# Dynamically create gitlab-ci variables starting from a script

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I’m trying to create a parent child pipeline on Gitlab using gitlab-ci but I need to share variables from parent to child pipeline.
I’m using the “options” capability to have a drop down menu with pre-filled values just to avoid TYPO while filling the variable.
Is there any way to create the options starting from a bash script?

For example:

```
variables:
  - myVar
    options:
      script:
        - find -type f | grep microservices
```

Thank you!
Cheers

Comment: No, but a similar question has some suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69764062/367456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native solution for this. However, I've approximated something like this using `pre-commit` hooks.

Basically, there is a `pre-commit` hook script that will generate the possible choices and edit the `variables:` key in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` to contain all the appropriate options whenever they change. I also setup [pre-commit autofixing](https://stackoverflow.com/at/71270196/5747944) in the GitLab pipeline so you never have stale options.